# Picasso is not loading images from Real path custom adapter

Tags: android, picasso

The .setImageBitmap works for this but for some reason picasso isn't working.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater zainsInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = zainsInflater.inflate(R.layout.img_layout, parent, false);
    String singleImg = getItem(position);
    ImageView imgdb = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.img_db);
    //Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(singleImg);
    //imgdb.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(singleImg).resize(50,50).into(imgdb);
    return customView;
}
```

Using picasso doesn't cause it to crash. It just doesn't display anything, however using .setImageBitmap does.

Thanks

Comment: What is `singleImg`?

Comment: singleImg is the real Path

Comment: Feel free to explain, in detail, what "the real Path" means. You may wish to consider showing a few sample values of `singleImg` and the code from which you get "the real Path".

Comment: an example of singleImg is: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/img1.jpg

Comment: It *might* be the current bug in picasso with MarkableInputStream. Search in the issues on GitHub and you will find a couple pull requests that fix it. I had to fork picasso and use one of the pull requests to get it working.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. I changed .load(singleImg) to .load(new File(singleImg))